# Restart with threshold

Tags: akka, akka-stream

How to create a stream stage that will "forget" that it restarted after some time? I want to implement something similar to `RestartFlow` with the policy like "if the stage was restarted 3 times within 5 minutes, fail the stage. After 15 minutes after the last restart, forget that the stage ever restarted"

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of the box class with the behavior you desire. However looking at the source code of `RestartFlow.withBackoff` it looks like not very hard to modify it in a way you want. Under the hood it uses [RestartWithBackoffFlow](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/af525fd82a28e26bd6fe7409014bb719d4d79d51/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/RestartFlow.scala#L140) class, which in turn uses [RestartWithBackoffLogic](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/af525fd82a28e26bd6fe7409014bb719d4d79d51/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/RestartFlow.scala#L216). Just add one more `var` to remember when the last restart happened (it already has `var restartCount = 0` some state) and modify the function `maxRestartsReached` so it takes into account some "reset" timeout.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably `akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy` which allows configuring a tolerance of failures within a time window.

That is you need to implement a supervision strategy.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html